# Shortest path that visits all vertices in a directed complete weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph

Given: complete directed weighted graph. All weights are positive. Is there any simple way (heuristics?) to find the shortest (in terms of weights) path that visits all vertices? Number of vertices is around 25.
This problem seems to be close to Asymmetric Travelling Salesman, but I don't require this path to be the cycle.

Comment: Read [Hamiltonion path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).

Comment: Do the weights satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: Not necessary, but in most of the cases they do. I guess, I can assume that it is satisfied

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend K-shortest path approach:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32513-k-shortest-path-yen-s-algorithm

I think this is your best bet... Here is an example: lets say you have 8 nodes and need to get from node 1 to node 8 in the shortest path possible. Let's assume all nodes are connected to each other (i.e., node 1 is connected to node 2:8, and so on). You will have to generate the "cost matrix" based on your problem.

```
costMatrix = rand(8);
[shortestPath, cost] = dijkstra(costMatrix,1,8);

% Alternatively, return the 10 shortest paths from point 1 to 8:
[shortestPaths, costs] = kShortestPath(costMatrix,1,8,10);
```

Position (i,j) in the cost matrix is the cost of traveling from node i to node j. If `costMatrix(i,j) = inf;` there is no connection between node i and node j.

After looking into hidden markov models, I found a number of potential problems - the emission matrix would be difficult to define and you can run into problems where you would enter a "state" two or more times during a single "route." With the k-shortest path, this error doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've never heard about HMM, it looks very interesting, but I'm struggling with formulating my problem as HMM. I guess, weights can be normalized to probabilities, but what would be emissions of each vertex, and what sequence do I need to specify in order to find the path that covers all vertices?

Comment: thanks, chancea - I am in the process of editing my answer now :)

Comment: Evgenii, I will have an update in my post ASAP that will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, however, I still can't understand how K-shortest path approach will help me to find the path that contains all vertices? Obviously there are many pathes that are shorter but do not contain all vertices

Comment: You would have to use the `kShortestPath()` function and set it to find the first 100 (or something large) shortest paths and then find the first path that contains all vertices. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does, but in case of complete graph and 20 vertices, this is a computationally insane task. I tried to do it for 12 vertices, and Matlab is still busy after 12 hours

Comment: `>> tic; [sp,c] = kShortestPath(rand(12),1,12,5000); toc
Elapsed time is 207.380679 seconds.
>> max(cellfun(@length,sp))
ans =
    12`

This didn't take that long (i.e., 12 is the number of vertices, and  the above function did indeed find paths that travel from all vertices.... It would probably take a couple of hours to do 20 vertices.... I don't know what code is out there to provide a boundary condition that requires all vertices in the path.